# Property '{nameOfProperty}' not found on type Bean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, propertynotfoundexception

I keep getting this exception: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'totalMaleTrainers' not found on type com.beans.Report` when I try to display the value of `totalMaleTrainers`, it works fine when I display the other values. **Note** that I just recently added this property in my `'Report' Bean`.

I already tried to search and find if others had the a same problem with mine but I didn't get the solution. I tried rewriting the `'Report' Bean` but I still get an `Exception`.

**REPORT BEAN**

```
public class Report {
  private Integer totalMaleTrainers;

  public Integer getTotalMaleTr() {
    return totalMaleTrainers;
  }
  public void setTotalMaleTr(Integer totalMaleTrainers) {
    this.totalMaleTrainers = totalMaleTrainers;
  }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
Report schoolReport = null;
try{
  schoolReport = reportmanager.getSchoolReport(sch_id);
  request.setAttribute("report", schoolReport);
}
```

**JSP**

```
<p>${report.totalMaleTrainers}</p>
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'totalMaleTrainers' not found on type com.beans.Report
```

I also tried to convert it to a `JSONObject` using `GSON()` to test if `totalMaleTrainers` is in it and it is.

```
{"totalRoadTrainers":190,"totalMaleTrainers":214}
```

Comment: `totalMaleTrainers` doesn't have a getter or a setter, does it? Seems like you renamed the field but forgot to do the same for related getter/setter

Comment: @ernest_k It has a getter and setter.

Comment: But there's no getter/setter for it in the `Report` class you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call getter method:

```
<p>${report.getTotalMaleTr()}</p>
```

Or make your property `public`:

```
public Integer totalMaleTrainers;
```

Or try recreate getter method using your IDE

Comment: Thanks man, calling the getter method worked. But why isn't `${report.totalMaleTrainers}` working though? I tried it with other properties in the bean and they work.

Comment: @j.ian.le maybe your getter/setter isn't following conventions, should be `getTotalMaleTrainers()` and `setTotalMaleTrainers()`

Comment: I was getting this error: `Property [timestamp] not found on type [com..beans.Emp]` Thanks I finally fixed it by `getters` and `setters` as well as by calling" `${report.getTimestamp()}` Great. +1